# Defining structure with elements present conditionally

Tags: c, struct, unions

I am trying to define a C structure where an element is present conditionally. Here is the specific example of a header that I want to define:

```
typedef struct flowHeader { 
    int magicNum ;
    int trafficType ;
    // few other int parameters
    int flowDirection; // Present ONLY if trafficType = TT_V6
    // few other int parameters 
} t_flowHeader ;
```

---

I want to know what's the best way to define this data type. I want to apply this header to a buffer that is received on wire. Because of one element missing - the size of structure varies by 4 bytes and I am struggling how to manage that?

```
# define TT_V6 31
# define FD_NA 0
int flowDir ;
unsigned char buf[ MAXSZ ] ;
t_flowHeader * hdr ; 


hdr = (t_flowHeader *) buf ; 
if (hdr->trafficType == TT_V6) {
    flowDir = hdr->flowDirection ; 
} else {
    flowDir = FD_NA ; 
}
```

..

Comment: Rearrange the 4bytes in the buf before dereferencing

Comment: That's not an option - at some point down the logic I need serialize this structure ... So changing order is not a choice. Also that will completely change the speed advantage I get by casting my header on to incoming message buffer.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use two separate types. You can reduce duplication by defining nested types for all of the other shared components:

```
struct flowHeader_start { 
    int magicNum ;
    int trafficType ;
    // few other int parameters
};

struct flowHeader_end {
    // few other int parameters 
};

typedef struct flowHeaderA { 
    struct flowHeader_start s;
    int flowDirection; // Present ONLY if trafficType = TT_V6
    struct flowHeader_end e;
} t_flowHeaderA ;

typedef struct flowHeaderB {
    struct flowHeader_start s; struct flowHeader_end e;
} t_flowHeaderB ;
```

...then rearrange the casts a bit:

```
if (((struct flowHeader_start *)buf)->trafficType == TT_V6) {
    hdr = (t_flowHeaderA *) buf ; 
    flowDir = hdr->flowDirection ; 
} else {
    hdr = (t_flowHeaderB *) buf ;
    flowDir = FD_NA ; 
}
```

The type itself isn't dependent on a condition, but where each of the two possible types is *used* is dependent on it.

The structure of both types up to the end of the `struct flowHeader_start` is also guaranteed to be exactly the same (because they have the same first element, and a struct must begin at the first element without padding), so you can cast between either type and `struct flowHeader_start` safely, meaning that you can test for conditions placed within the first block without knowing the form of the rest of the buffer.

As an extension, some compilers might also let you make the nested structs anonymous, which would be more convenient to look at, not having to access elements of the last struct through the intermediate `e` field (can't remember if the standard allows this for named types, I think not).

Comment: This was indeed one of the options I thought of. As you rightly pointed - it involves one more check - and this code being in fastpath - I have a small perf hit. I was looking to avoid this penalty.

Comment: ? This involves exactly one check, same as the code in the question..?

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think you can vary the size of the structure on the basic of a condition.

1. You can define multiple structures and use them accordingly>
2. or define those elements which are supposed to be conditionally present at the end of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this.

C is a *static* language, which is why you must declare things in the first place. The compiler must be able to generate code before the program runs, the code can't change based on runtime requirements like that.

You're going to have to declare two different structures and then select the proper one based on runtime data using `if` tests and so on.

Comment: Thanks - as I wrote on earlier comment - one more if check is a potential performance hit for me ... I was looking to avoid that one.